# Do terminators have a sense of smell and taste?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

Obviously, terminators can see and hear, but can they smell and taste, as humans do?

Comment: I doubt they'd be programmed to experience the senses the way humans do. Probably closer to sensors (to identify and cross-index components / molecules) than organs (that can experience stinking scents and bitter or sweet flavors, etc).

Comment: @MeatTrademark I dunno, it could have some uses. For example the infiltrator type Terminators would benefit if they knew how someone they were going to impersonate smells so they could maintain the same aroma.

Comment: I like that @T-1000 is asking all of these questions about human knowledge of terminators, *almost as if its trying to figure out how much we know...*

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Call to John.

Comment: Q. How does a Terminator smell? A. With his nose. Duh.

Answer (score 21):

### Smell

The Terminator (T-800) certainly has a sense of smell, as you can see from the image below from the 'biker bar' scene from T2 : Judgement Day.

The Terminator has cigar smoke blown in his face, which he correctly determines as "*carcinogenic vapor*".

[image]

### Taste

In T3:Rise of the Machines we see the T-X Terminator using her tongue to sample blood. Note that the graphic shows that whilst she does this primarily as a means of delivering the blood to a DNA analyser, it also identifies (more immediately) that the initial sample contains "Material: Cotton" and "Blood".

[image]

Comment: Neither of these are compelling examples. They both seem more like merely *analyzing* samples as opposed to actual scent or flavor. "Why hell now, that there tastes like one a' them John Connor fellas I'm a' lookin' fer!" *(I have no idea why I decided she's suddenly a hillbilly. Sorry about that.)*

Comment: We analyse food the same way by interacting with the molecules and determining their "smell" and "taste" as to whether they are favorable to us or not. Since the terminators are gathering information using those senses, they would most certainly be considered to have a sense of taste and smell. It seems reasonable that they should given the advantages such environmental biological information gathering could give them in tracking human targets. Let's face it, no one is going to be terribly fresh in a future where water is in short supply...

Comment: @MeatTrademark - Note that the T-X firstly identifies cotton and blood rather than immediately sampling the DNA.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - How would you define taste and smell then, if not the process of analysing samples? All taste and scent consists of is molecules held in suspension...

Comment: Seems more likely that they just *identify* the molecules as opposed to *experiencing* them the way we do. The way computers can analyze samples. Computers don't really smell, they identify. Keep in mind the skin is there just to send Terminators through time; they aren't people.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - You're getting all philosophical. How does a machine analysing and reacting to a particular molecule differ from a human "experiencing" a scent comprised of the same molecules?

Comment: Here's the difference. Terminator: (reading output of analysis) this is [whatever the hell components make up a skunk's spray]. Human: ewwww, that stinks!

Comment: The T-X's physical reaction to the taste was almost orgasmic. "Was it good for you?"

Comment: @MeatTrademark "eww, that stinks" is actually a response to the initial reaction "this smells rancid, it is unsafe to eat". Revulsion is a reaction to the initial analysis.

Comment: I think the concept that's in discussion is whether a Terminator experiences [qualia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia).

Comment: Give a cat some food they aren't familiar with, and they'll dab at it with their tongue first to see if it's acceptable food. When a dog meets a new person, they start smelling them. They aren't trying to see if they're wearing too much cologne, they want to make sure they aren't up to something bad. That's why people hold their hands out, palms up, to let new dogs smell them. Taste and smell aren't gifts from god to indulge in the world, they're tools to analyze and understand the world around you.

Comment: @MeatTrademark By the same logic you can argue that machines don't really "see" or "hear" either. They just identify and process various light wavelengths and sound waves.

Comment: @Richard - [Here's](https://farm1.staticflickr.com/435/19489477871_0d2b53f405_o_d.jpg) a screenshot of it.  The HUD definitely says "Material:  Cotton"

Comment: @WadCheber - Ah yes. I think I got that from the screenplay, not the film.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The DNA analysis example is a bit different than true taste, and even the example of the Terminator detecting carcinogenic smoke is not quite the same thing as smell, but the experience humans describe as "smell" is actually the chemical analysis of particulate matter in the air being inhaled.  The sense of taste is partially processed by the olfactory system, which means that it, too, is partially chemical analysis.  In this case, more than any other of the Terminators' senses, the similarities between human and Terminator senses outweigh the differences.

Comment: It might even work more or less the same way.  We have different kinds of chemical receptors in our nasal passages and sinuses, which are connected to different kinds of receptors in the olfactory section of the brain, and the different types of receptors are each responsible for detecting a specific type of chemical.  The Terminator sensory systems probably work the same way.

Answer (score 5):

In [T3](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_3:_Rise_of_the_Machines_(film)), the T-X samples blood with her tongue, implying some form of sensory input in the tongue.

In TSCC, [Cameron Phillips](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Cameron) eats chips, although whether she got anything out of it is [a totally different question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14737/what-makes-a-terminator-a-cyborg/14741#14741).

[image]

As to whether or not they smell,  <s>I don't recall anything from the movies. The closest I can recall is in T1, [when the T-800 was rotting in the hotel room](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22360/why-was-the-first-terminator-rotting).</s>  I forgot about the smoke in T2, as mentioned by Richard.

Comment: Where was Cameron when eating the chips?  If it was in private/only with the Connors, where there was no need to put up an act, then I'd see that as a point in favor of her just liking the chips

Comment: @Izkata I think the scene was outside a gas stop/convenience store. John was trying to get Cameron to be better at acting human or something.